# Java RAF - what if file is renamed

Tags: java, file-io

If I create a java Random Access File object against a file. What happens when the file is renamed?

case1. Let's say, I created a RAF object against test.log. Then I renamed test.log -> test1.log by doing something like

```
mv test.log test1.log
```

What happens to my RAF object then in this case?

case2. again, create a RAF object against test.log then:

```
mv test.log test1.log
touch test.log
```

in this case, is my object pointing to test.log or test1.log

case3. what if my RAF object is pointing to a log file which will be rotated eventually?

Most importantly, can someone explain to me what happens under the cover? like how the RAF object points/refers to the actual file, how it works when file is renamed or deleted.

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself on your environment?

Comment: sorry, I should have said this, I am more looking for the explanation how exactly RAF object is pointing to the file, and how that pointer gets affected when file is renamed and deleted.

Comment: There isn't one. It is operating system dependent. You cannot rename an open file on Windows; you can on some other systems e.g. I believe Linux and Unix - but I'm open to correction. THere is no magic about the 'RAF object pointing to the file'. It is an open file, period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

===========================

My Own test

===========================

```
    RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile("/tmp/test_log", "rw"); 
    System.out.print("file created"); //======lineA======
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        System.out.print("finish sleeping");
        int i = (int) rand.length(); //=====lineB=====
        rand.seek(0); // Seek to start point of file
        for (int ct = 0; ct < i; ct++) {
            byte b = rand.readByte(); // read byte from the file
            System.out.print((char) b); // convert byte into char
        }
    }
```

test case 1:

remove the test_log file after lineA before lineB, it finishes reading the whole file without any problems/Exceptions.

test case 2:

mv /tmp/test_log /tmp/test_log.bk after lineA before lineB, again,it finishes reading the whole file without any problems/Exceptions.

test case 3:

following test case 2, start writing extra lines to /tmp/test_log.bk,

```
echo "test line1 bla bla" >> /tmp/test_log.bk
echo "test line2 bla bla" >> /tmp/test_log.bk
```

it reads the whole file now problem, PLUS, it reads the new lines added in test_log.bk as well.

Answer (score 4):

I did a little test:

- Created a random access file, and popped out a joption pane.
- While the dialog was open I deleted the file which it was perfectly allowed.
- Then tried to write on the file and closed it which happened silently.

At least on my linux machine it behaves like it.

When I tried moving the file, the contents got written no matter successfully.

For the case 2, the contents will be written to "test1.log" which is the one you're pointing to.

For the 3d case, no, the file wont be rotated eventually.

Sorry for the previous wild guess.

Comment: Really? what about case 3 I just added in?

Comment: I also edited to expand the explanation, but basically you wont be able to move the file when a program is using it.